# How to find vector in following context

Tags: vectors

I am making a video game, and when player tries to walk into wall he should slide along it. However I am confused how to resolve the vectors for it. Here is image illustrating problem: 
[image]

I know the v vector, as well as angles A and B (although angle A is wrongly illustrated here, it should be counter clockwise). How do I find b vector?

Comment: The angle of incidence will only determine if it slides left or right, the direction is otherwise fixed by the wall and could be pre-calculated. Is the magnitude of the vector preserved?

Comment: @user121049 well v = a + b, thus the magnitude should be different if A=/=B.

Comment: Assuming that $\vec{a}$ is a unit vector (it should be, and you should know it too, since it's a property of your wall!) then the component of $\vec{v}$ that's parallel to the direction $\vec{a}$ is $(\vec{v}\cdot\vec{a})\vec{a}$, and the component of $\vec{v}$ that's perpendicular to $\vec{a}$ - in other words, your $\vec{b}$ - is $\vec{v}-(\vec{v}\cdot\vec{a})\vec{a}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hustle I found the solution:

|b| = cos (A - B) * |v|

bx = cosB * |b|

by = sinB * |b|

Comment: You can do this with _much_ less trigonometry than this - you should never have to calculate a sine or cosine at all here.